# 3-phase Voltage Measurement

Tags: three-phase

I have a 3-phase system, where I measuring the Phase-Neutral voltage of each of the phases. Is it possible to calculate the Phase to Phase voltage from these values, even if the voltages are unbalanced?

I am measuring the instant voltage of each of the phases in sequence with an ADC.The time interval between each phase measurement is 25uS.The next "batch" of measurements is taken after 500uS.At the end of each sine cycle I am calculating the Vavg of each Phase and displaying it. Since it is usually a balanced voltage, I am just multiplying each phase voltage by 1.732 and displaying it. eg. 240V * 1.732 = 415V.

This will not hold good if the phase voltages are not equal, hence my query. Hence was looking for some ideas on implement this with a 10bit ADC on a 8bit uC.

Comment: Sure. It's just trigonometry one you draw the diagram. Have a go and post it into your question. Alternatively use a CAD program to draw it and measure the result.

Answer (score 2):

Balanced or unbalanced the phase-phase voltage is always the difference of the respective line voltages.

$$V_{ab}=V_a-V_b$$

and so on. (Did I get it right what you asked?)

==

Then, if you want to quantify unbalance (e.g. different amplitudes of the three phases or uneven angles, deviating from the ideal 120 deg) you need to express all into one of the commonly used indexes:

Voltge Unblance Factor (VUF) is simply $$\textrm{VUF} = V_- / V_+$$,
where V_+ and V_- are the voltage positive and negative sequence.

Positive, negative and zero sequence components can be extracted by rotating
0, 120, 240 (positive), 0, 240, 120 (negative), and 0, 0, 0 (zero).

[image]

[Matrix form to extract 0,+ and - sequence from three-phase voltages Va, Vb, Vc (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetrical_components)]

$$\alpha = \mathrm{e}^{(2/3i\pi)}$$

==

IEEE Std. 112 speaks of $$\textrm{PVUR} = \textrm{MVDPV} / \textrm{APV}$$,
where
PVUR = Percent Voltge Unbalance Ratio,
MVDAPV is Maximum Voltage Deviation from Average Phase Voltage,
APV is Average Phase Voltage
This is to be intended to be useful on a longer time interval, so e.g. over  day, 1 month, 1 year.

Comment: Good answer and for abc rotation system. Swap 2nd and 3rd rows of \$A^{-1}\$ for acb rotation system.

Comment: @andrea : Thanks for answering. I am measuring the instant voltage of each of the phases in sequence with an ADC.The time interval between each phase measurement is 25uS. At the end of each sine cycle I am calculating the Vavg of each Phase and displaying it. Since it is usually a balanced voltage, I am just multiplying each phase voltage by 1.732 and displaying it. eg. 240V * 1.732 = 415V. This will not hold good if the phase voltages are not equal, hence my query. Hence was looking for some ideas on implement this  with a 10bit ADC on a 8bit uC.

Comment: @EmbSysDev Your problem is then more "articulated". 1) sample time = 25 us, 2)  time-domain waveform => 3) V quantities are rms, so you need to estimate it from waveform; 3a) simple square root of sum of squares (all harmonics, all ...), OR 3b) extraction of fundamental (e.g FFT). {3b) preferred, so you have ampl + phase} => 4) calc Vab as diff of FFT "phasors" and you know everything.  --Note: FFT can be optimized for the next power of 2... if you go t 19.53 us you get 1024 samples. ; I can add details in the answer above

Comment: Sample time is 25uS between each phase measurement. It is as fast as possible to go currently on this uC. The next batch of measurement is after 500uS.I have never implemented FFT alogorithms in C, so if some simpler idea assuming pure sine wave with ideal 120deg @50Hz would be possible then I could try that first. Thanks much!

Comment: You're welcome! So you interleave the sampling, cycling between the 3 phases, each one 25 us, so resulting sample time is 75 us for 1 phase (13.33 kHz). But then you speak of batch of measurements after 500 us, whereas sampling in time domain should be uniform: could you add details to your question? Note: be careful that you have a phase shift among phase samples due to cyclic sampling : for accurate phase diff estimate you should compensate it.

Comment: @andrea, apologies for the delay ,we live in uncertain times :)... Will try to clarify a bit more : Rsample,25uS,Ysample,25uS,Bsample, 500uS , Rsample,25uS,Ysample25uS,Bsample, 500uS .... and so on.After 20 samples (half cycle) , the values of each phase are averaged, thus I get the P-N values, which is good enough. Then I multiply each phase value by 1.732 to displays P-P value , this is good enough if all the phase voltages are balanced and equal.

Comment: My query :If it is possible to calculate the P-P voltages from the readings I have taken, so that it will be accurate even if the voltages are unbalanced. I would like if you could give some coding algorithm (my higher math skills, are quite "fundamental" )